# How to add new webpart to an existing spfx project

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I have an existing sharepoint framework (SPFX) project. Now I want to create a custom search web part. So how can I add a new webaprt to existing solution

PS: I am very new to SPFx. TIA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open the existing directory structure containing spfx  in the command prompt.

After that simply call the yeoman generator again, fill up the details like webpart name, desc etc and it will automatically detect, handle and add the new webpart to the existing solution.

```
yo @microsoft/sharepoint
```

Run this in the command prompt.

For example below, I first created a webpart (helloworld) in `E:\test-spfx` folder. After that i ran the generator again and created another webpart `hello2` in the same folder, it will add the webpart named hello2 in the same solution.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice! But is it possible to combine already existing webparts in one solutions....so basically if I have `webaprt_a` and `webpart_b` can I move `webpart_b` into `webpart_a`?

Comment: @JohnRambo: if the SPFX version are aligned (if not upgrade the older WP to the same version of the newer), you can : 1. copy the webpart sources (`./src/webparts/webpart_a`), 2. Update the "manifest" (`./config/config.json`) to include both webparts.